# Admin URL resolver to pass a filtering argument

Tags: django, url, django-admin

I want to add a link in an admin form to show the children of the clicked object.

In my model I have:

```
    def change_form_link(self):
            changeform_url = urlresolvers.reverse('admin:customerData_wifirouter_changelist'
            return '<a href="%s" >Change</a>' % changeform_url
    change_form_link.allow_tags = True
```

Everything works fine here, and I get my link to the admin page to change my "wifirouters".

But I need to filter this page by building.

So I tried:

```
    def change_form_link(self):
            changeform_url = urlresolvers.reverse('admin:customerData_wifirouter_changelist', args=[self.building_label,])
            return '<a href="%s" >Change</a>' % changeform_url
    change_form_link.allow_tags = True
```

And I get a bad error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/customerData/customer/1/

Reverse for 'customerData_wifirouter_changelist' with arguments '('4 rue de Douai',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/customerData/wifirouter/$']
```

On the other hand, my admin filtered page works fine at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/customerData/wifirouter/?building__building_label=4+rue+de+Douai` .

I understand that I am using the bas syntax to link to the filtered admin page.

Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The querystring `?building__building_label=4+rue+de+Douai` is not part of the url that is reversed. You can reverse the url, then add the querystring to it.

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
# In Python 2 from urllib import urlencode

changeform_url = urlresolvers.reverse('admin:customerData_wifirouter_changelist')
querydict = {'building__building_label': self.building_label}
changeform_url = '%s?%s' % (changeform_url, urlencode(querydict))
```

Using urlencode ensures that the string is url encoded (e.g. the spaces are converted to `+` signs).